# How can I fix the gpg-agent: Bad CPU type problem?

Tags: catalina, gpg

If I log in my account (osx 10.15.6), I get from the start-gpg-agent.app an error message:

error "sh: /usr/local/bin/gpg-agent: Bad CPU type in executable" number 126

How can I fix it? Apple support recommend to change the default shell to zsh. But this not change the error.

Comment: Then Apple support are giving the wrong advice. But as gpg-agent is not an apple program then how are they expected to know. How did you install it?

Answer (score 3):

Most probably you have `gpg-agent` installed in a 32-bit version. macOS 10.15 only supports 64-bit programs, so it tells you the CPU type in the executable is not supported.

The fix is to reinstall gpg-agent in the 64-bit version.

You can check the type of executable by running the following in the Terminal:

```
file /usr/local/bin/gpg-agent
```

Most probably it will say:

```
/usr/local/bin/gpg-agent: Mach-O executable i386
```

Here "i386" means that it is compiled for a 32-bit CPU architecture.

After replacing gpg-agent with the 64-bit version, you should see an output like:

```
/usr/local/bin/gpg-agent: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Comment: You can check this with `file /usr/local/bin/gpg-agent` -- if it lists the type as "Mach-O executable i386", it's 32-bit only. To work under Catalina, it should be "Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64" (or "Mach-O universal binary" including that).

Comment: Thanks!! Should I only update gpg-agent not start-gpg-agent.app?

Comment: I would just update the whole thing - you want to be updated anyways.

Comment: Hi I'm seeing the same issue for `yq`, I'm not familiar with Mac system, can I ask how I can update it from 32-bites to 64-bites? I raised a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70972303/how-to-install-yq-with-mach-o-64-bit-executable-i-got-error-bad-cpu-executab